# how to connect ftp and copy the file from one folder to another folder inside FTP by SSJS or SOAP API in exacttarget?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, ssjs

We need to copy the folder inside the ftp but we need to write the script so that we can add it in Automation and side by side we have two files.

we have tried by .net please check it.
Thanks in advance.

```
//To Connect to ftp
private bool TryConnect()
 {
  bool ret = false;
  try {
   FTP = new FTPConnection();
   FTP.ServerAddress = "192.108.1.10";//Server IP address
   FTP.UserName = "username";//server user name
   FTP.Password = "******";//Password
   FTP.ConnectMode = FTPConnectMode.PASV;
   FTP.Connect();
   ret = FTP.IsConnected;

  } catch (Exception ex) {
  }
  return ret;
 }

//To Send File
if (TryConnect()) 
{
FTP.UploadFile("Directory", "File Name", false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ampscript and SSJS do not support much in terms of fine file manipulation on FTP.  Best practice is to simple use FTP with third party code or applications that were built for that use case.  SMC will be frustrating and/or disappointing for this.

Lame, i know, but SMC is a marketing tool first, file manipulation tool second.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Enhanced FTP File Move and Copy" Data Extract type to move a file from one folder to another. 
Log a case with SFMC support to enable it and then use it in an automation.

reference link - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000230276&type=1